# How to get code coverage on test that needs service to be hosted?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution with a test project that has tests that call a class library project which calls a WCF service project (this is a simplified summary of the status, the actual solution is more complex).

From the Test Explorer if I click on 'Debug Selected Tests' the tests then pass but if I 'Run Selected Tests' then they fail as the service is not being hosted.

I want to check my code coverage but the code coverage 'runs' the tests which means the service does not get hosted and thus the tests fail and my code coverage is 0%.

How can I configure the testing process so that the service is hosted when I 'run' tests as well as when I 'debug' tests?

Addendum

After consideration I think that mocking the service will not accomplish the goal. The various components have already been tested in isolation using mocking but now need to be tested to see how they operate together.

Answer (score 2):

They're not unittests as they have an external dependency (another example is a database call) - you are relying on the webservice being up for the test to pass. This isnt a guarantee.

I'd say use a mocking framework here - I use Rhino Mocks but there are plenty out there. That way you can bypass the reliance on the webservice by mocking it.

In addition - I'd look at refactoring the class library you're calling if you can, seperate out the calls etc so you can test parts in isolation.

Comment: I already have tested parts in isolation, I'm trying to test the interdependencies between the components. I'll think about the mocking although I'm not sure it actually does what I'm looking for.